# DB2(SQL)¿Cómo funciona la caché?

Tags: sql, db2

Hola buenas estoy utilizando DB2 y mi pregunta es: tengo una tabla con `id_campos` y otra con `id_Casas`, hago un `union all` antes de este `select` de las dos para que funcione mejor el cacheo, o lo hago así y reduzco los campos comparados? Los datos que habrán en cada tabla serán al menos **50 mil** o **100 mil**, es mejor el cacheo o reducir el tamaño de la tabla comparado?

Hago un:

```
insert into edificios(id)
(select id_campos as id
from id campos
inner join blabla
inner join blabla
union all
select id_casas as id
from id_casas
inner join blabla
inner join blabla
union all
select id_casas as id
from id_casas
inner join blabla
inner join blabla
union all
select id_casas as id
from id_casas
inner join blabla
inner join blabla)
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta respuesta es un poco especulativa.  Si el poder de selección del inner join es muy grande (si el número de registros se reduce sustancialmente por efecto del inner join), funcionaría mejor como lo tienes en el ejemplo.  Por el contrario, si el poder de selección del inner join es muy bajo (el número de registros no se reduce sustancialemnte o incluso se aumenta), mejor haces primero el union all.